# How to inspect all cookies in chrome devtools?

Tags: cookies, path, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome devtools shows only the cookies related to the current url (based on path attribute), how can I see all the cookies related to a domain ?

Comment: Use an extension.

Comment: Using chrome : chrome://settings/content/cookies

Comment: @wOxxOm, do you know of a particular extension that enables this?

Answer (score 2):

Update 2021:

Using Chrome: `chrome://settings/siteData?searchSubpage=localhost&search=cookies`

Print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DYAy.png

Comment: For Chrome 111.0.5563.146, the URL is chrome://settings/content/all?search=cookies